# Migrate drupal 7 full content type to drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, migration, drupal-8

I'm working on a new drupal 8 website.
I have already a drupal 7 installation with severals content type (custom field image, date etc ...) and i dont know what is the best pratice to migrate thoses contents types to my new drupal 8 installation..
**Does someone know how to do that properly ?**
Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [this document](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrading-from-drupal-6-or-7-to-drupal-8) can help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate using Migrate API(https://www.drupal.org/node/2127611) of Drupal 8. In Drupal 8, some core modules are there which you can configure and use. Those are Migrate, Migrate Drupal and Migrate Drupal UI. Also some contrib modules are there as well - Migrate Upgrade, Migrate Tools, Migrate Plus and Migrate Manifest.